# Visual Source Save Configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-sourcesafe, vssettings

I'm using VSS version 8.0.5. I've installed it on server. I've added visual studio 2010 project in it.

now on my system, i point the source control vss in my visual studio envionrnment. I configure the project on my working folder and then set the solution file in the IIS. When i open the solution then it was not being configured and not showing checkin/checkout.

Can you anyone give me the idea what can be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean by "not showing checkin/checkout". Do you mean the solution is not bound to VSS? If yes, how did you open the solution? Please try to open it from source control and see how it works.